# Retrofit null response in a success request 200

Tags: android, rest, android-studio, nullreferenceexception, retrofit2

when I try to login in my system it return a User object from backend, and it is returning this json with http 200:

```
{
"data": [1]
  0:{
   "id": 14
   "name": "Adam"
   "email": "email@gmail.com"
   "password": "adam"
   "avatar": ""
   "activity": ""
   "bio": ""
   "member_since": "0000-00-00"
   "remember_token": null
   "created_at": "2016-05-17 17:10:42"
   "updated_at": "2016-05-17 17:10:42"
   }-
   -
}
```

All is apparently ok.
But in Android studio I obtain a null object when I'm access to response.body()

My method in the interface for login is this:

```
@GET("users/{name}/{password}")
    Call<UserDTO> login(@Path("name") String name, @Path("password") String password);
```

And this is the part I obtain the error:

```
Call<UserDTO> call = mRestApi.getService().login(email, password);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<UserDTO>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserDTO> call, Response<UserDTO> response) {
                //call.cancel();
                if(response.code() == 401) //login incorrecto
                {
                    onLoginFailed();

                }else if(response.code() == 200) {
                    //TODO usuario nulo al venir de una peticion rest

                    Log.d("DEBUG",  response.body().getUser().getName());
                    onLoginSuccess();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserDTO> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error de conexión al servidor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

In this line it is failing:

```
Log.d("DEBUG",  response.body().getUser().getName());
```

Finally Android Studio's error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: myapp.myapp, PID: 3349
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String myapp.flattomate.Model.User.getName()' on a null object reference
```

I'm using now DTO pattern, but without this I obtain the same error.

What is happening?

**EDIT**
Retrofit class:

```
public class restAPI {

    private static final String ENDPOINT = "http://192.168.2.102:8000/";
    private final FlattomateService mService;

    public interface FlattomateService{
        @GET("users/{username}")
        Call<User> getUser(@Path("username") Integer username);

        @GET("users/index")
        Call<List<UserDTO>> allUsers();

        @GET("group/{id}/users")
        Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId, @Query("sort") String sort);

        @POST("users")
        Call<User> register(@Body User user);

        @GET("users/{name}/{password}")
        Call<UserDTO> login(@Path("name") String name, @Path("password") String password);


    }

    public restAPI(){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .serializeNulls()
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        mService = retrofit.create(FlattomateService.class);
    }

    public FlattomateService getService(){ return mService; }


}
```

UserDTO.java:

```
public class UserDTO {

    User user;

    public User getUser() { return user; }
}
```

User.java:

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("avatar")
    @Expose
    private String avatar;
    @SerializedName("activity")
    @Expose
    private String activity;
    @SerializedName("bio")
    @Expose
    private String bio;
    @SerializedName("member_since")
    @Expose
    private String memberSince;

    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    public User(){}

    public User(String name, String email, String password){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;

    }
    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * The name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param email
     * The email
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The avatar
     */
    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param avatar
     * The avatar
     */
    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The activity
     */
    public String getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param activity
     * The activity
     */
    public void setActivity(String activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The bio
     */
    public String getBio() {
        return bio;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param bio
     * The bio
     */
    public void setBio(String bio) {
        this.bio = bio;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The memberSince
     */
    public String getMemberSince() {
        return memberSince;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param memberSince
     * The member_since
     */
    public void setMemberSince(String memberSince) {
        this.memberSince = memberSince;
    }


}
```

Comment: So onReponse() gets called but that statement is null. Have you tried accessing other fields to see if they also return null?

Comment: If object is null the access to methods return null as well

Comment: I am thinking about parsed data from json are wrong, because this output:

D/Call request: Request{method=GET, url=http://192.168.2.102:8000/users/email@gmail.com/pass, tag=null}
D/Response body: {}

Comment: Are you logging your retrofit? It should tell you the URL it's getting. Copy and paste that into your browser and see if the request was malformed.

Comment: this is what return in browser:

{"data":[{"id":16,"name":"Kaka","email":"kaka@kak.com","password":"kaka","avatar":"","activity":"","bio":"","member_since":"0000-00-00","remember_token":null,"created_at":"2016-05-17 18:13:42","updated_at":"2016-05-17 18:13:42"}]}

Apparently all is ok

Comment: And that's from the link you get in the logcat from retrofit?

Comment: this is the content shows in browser.
Retrofit and logcat in Android Studio shows what I pasted before.
 D/Response body: {}

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the service class for Retrofit?

Comment: edited and added my rest service class

Comment: can you put UserDTO class ?

Comment: userDTO and User added

Comment: Your code looks okay! Is it userDTO list of user ? if so you should define List<User>

Comment: Yeah I don't see interceptors. It doesn't look like you're logging. Do you know how to add those?

Comment: I just include userDTO to follow DTO pattern but is just a class for pass data between objects. I want just return one User in the login process for get data and save it in a sharedpreference object for mantain session in the app

Comment: No I don't how add interceptor, I added one a few minutes ago because I was viewing a tutorial. But same error.

Comment: Yeah it won't solve the problem. It'll give you a more verbose logcat. Once you get them working, post your logcat as well.

Comment: logcat shows the same error. I implemented this too:
https://futurestud.io/blog/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit

But the same again, same error.

Can be the way laravel make the response? because is my backend

Comment: what makes you think your `UserDTO` object matches the structure of the response? the 2 things are completely different!

Comment: I am trying just with User and the problem is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the json laravel send:

```
$response = Response::make(json_encode(['data'=>$user]), 200)->header('Location', $BASE_URL.$user->id)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
```

Laravel was sending an array that retrofit doesn't knew how to treat.

The solution was just send the $user like this:

```
$response = Response::make(json_encode($user), 200)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```